# Check for Nothing in vbscript/classic asp

Tags: arrays, asp-classic

I need to update an old classic asp, and I have to call a function that normally returns an array, but under certain circumstances might return either `Nothing` or an undefined value.

How can I check that the result actually returns an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the function late bound / has a `Variant` return value? If so, the `IsArray` function will check whether it contains an array type.

Answer (score 5):

er... I could be wrong, but isn't it just something like

```
If something Is Nothing Then
   'Do something here
Else
   'Do what I used to
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

IsNull() should work I think.

Comment: It needs to check for Nothing and not Null. Null and Nothing are totaly different values.

Answer (score 2):

If TypeName(something) = "Empty" Then
   ...

Comment: It needs to test agains "Nothing" and not "Empty"

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, but functional!

```
Function IsNothingType( ByRef obj )
    If TypeName(obj) = "Nothing" Then
        IsNothingType = True
    Else
        IsNothingType = False
    End If  
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using VBScript/WSH then you may want to try the "typeof" function/method.  It worked for me while the above did not.

Comment: `typeof` doesn't exists in VBScript.